# Rest Framework serialezer Not allowing a post like request from my react-native frontend

Tags: react-native, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement a like function in a react-native and Django project that I have been working on. But some how anytime I click the like button I keep getting this error Method Not Allowed: /api/feed-post/1/ what could possible be the issue with my like function.
Here is my model

```
class FeedPost(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to="videos",blank=True,null=True)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    views = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="view")
    shared_body = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    shared_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='+')
    shared_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    like_feed_post = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='feedlike') 
    notifications       = GenericRelation(Notification)
```

Here is my serializer view for post

```
class FeedPostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = FeedPost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FeedPostSerializer
    
    def like(self, request, pk=None):
        post = self.get_object()
        user = request.user

        if user in post.like_feed_post.all():
            post.like_feed_post.remove(user)
            liked = False
        else:
            post.like_feed_post.add(user)
            liked = True

        return Response({'liked': liked}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Here is the seriailizer model

```
class FeedPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comment = FeedCommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=False, source='comments')
    images = FeedPostImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=False, source='postimage_set')
    username = serializers.SerializerMethodField()  # Add this field for username
    likes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()  # Add this field for likes
    profile_picture = serializers.SerializerMethodField()


    # Custom method to get the like URL
    def get_like_url(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        if request is not None:
            post_id = obj.id
            return request.build_absolute_uri(f'/api/feed-post/{post_id}/')
        return None


    class Meta:
        model = FeedPost
        fields = '__all__'
        # Include the custom method's result in the serialized data
        extra_fields = ['like_url']

    def get_likes(self, obj):
        # Return a list of usernames of users who liked the post
        return [user.username for user in obj.like_feed_post.all()]

    # Override to_representation to include extra fields in serialized data
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        representation['like_url'] = self.get_like_url(instance)
        return representation
```

this my frontend react-native code for post like

```
const userLiked = item.likes.includes(item.username); // Replace "currentUsername" with actual username

  const handleToggleLike = async (postId, isLiked) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/feed-post/${postId}/`);
      const { liked } = response.data;
      // Handle the response, update UI, etc.
      console.log(`Post ${postId} is ${liked ? 'liked' : 'unliked'}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error toggling like:', error);
      // Handle the error, e.g., show a message to the user.
      // You can set a state variable to indicate the error or show an error message.
    }
  };



 <TouchableOpacity style={styles.likeButton} onPress={() => onToggleLike(item.id)}>
          <FontAwesome
            name={userLiked ? 'thumbs-up' : 'thumbs-o-up'}
            size={20}
            color={userLiked ? 'blue' : '#888'}
          />
          <Text style={styles.likeButtonText}>
            {item.like_feed_post.length} {item.like_feed_post.length === 1 ? 'Like' : 'Likes'}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```